# How do I implement a slideshow of images from java servlets without hard-coding the images in my html?

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

As a learning exercise I have adapted a series of Java servlets written by BalusC to store a list of images uploaded in a mysql database. The application works fine and displays a list of the images in the sequence they are read from the database statically in html. Howver, I am trying to adapt the html to display these dynamically in a slideshow. I have found several examples on the internet but all of them seem to hard-code the names of images in the browser code. I'm looking for some way of transfering the images read from the database query to a slideshow in the client.

[The original source is here](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/fileupload.aspx)

After having researched several examples it seems that using javascript is the most common way for doing it, but I cannot find an example which does it dynamically here is my attempt (I am using javascript embedded with html within a java servlet) at it which fails to do more that print out the titles of the images in a consecutive list on the page (but no image):

`try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, userName, password);
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from photos");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        out.println("<h1>Photos</h1>");
        while ( rs.next()) {
              out.println("<h4>" + rs.getString("title") + "</h4>");
              out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
              out.println(" function clearScreen(){");
              out.println(" document.image.src=displayphoto?id=\" +  rs.getString(\"id\")\"");
              out.println(" document.body.innerHTML=\"\";");
              out.println(" setTimeout('clearScreen()','5000');}");
              out.println("</script>");
        }

        con.close();
    }`

Any pointers or suggestions on a better way of doing this, even purely with Java servlets would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Alastair

Comment: Have you considered using a JSP for creating your HTML?

Comment: what do you mean, "fails to do more than print the list ?" From what I read, the generated html will contains x times the definition of the clearScreen function (a slightly different definition at each time), and each function will try to do the same thing : set the "src" property of a single "image" element in your page. Is that what're trying to do ?

Comment: Dave, I have considered it but so far I am just learning and have never used jsp before just Java servlets.

Comment: phtrivier. I'm crudely trying to display each image as it is retrieved from the database into html using embedded javascript. My intention is to display a series of images (in exactly the same location of the webpage i.e. one writes over the top of the other ) with a time delay of a few seconds between displaying one image and the next. But all the examples I'm finding seem to hard-code a list of images in the javascript in an array within the same javascript. I don't know what my images will be before runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This code generates a `<script>` block defining the same `clearScreen` function for each photo found in the table (but with a different photo ID at each iteration).

It's not very clear what you're trying to do. To do a slideshow, you have to iterate over a list of picture IDs. You can store this list of IDs

- as a JavaScript array in the HTML code. The servlet code would have to generate the JavaScript code defining an array of IDs
- as an Iterator at server-side, in a session attribute. To display the next photo, the displayphoto servlet would have to get the iterator from the session, get its next ID, and serve the bytes of the image having this ID
- nowhere. Each time a new photo must be displayed, its index would be passed to the displayphoto servlet, and the servlet would generate a SQL query to get the photo at this index. Of course, the SQL query would have to use some sort order to always return the photos in the same order.

If your goal is to implement the first solution, it's really not difficult. Here is how an array of three IDs (id1, id2 and id3) is declared in JavaScript:

```
var ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
```

So, all you have to do is to generate the above String frm a `List<String>` containing `"id1"`, `"id2"` and `"id3"`. A simple loop will do:

```
StringBuilder jsArrayDeclaration = new StringBuilder();
jsArrayDeclaration.append("var ids = [");
boolean first = true;
for (String id : listOfIds) {
    if (!first) {
        jsArrayDeclaration.append(", ");
    }
    first = false;
    jsArrayDeclaration.append("'");
    jsArrayDeclaration.append(id);
    jsArrayDeclaration.append("'");
}
jsArrayDeclaration.append("];");
```

Comment: JB Nizet, I guess what I'm trying to figure out is how do I generate the arraylist in java (actually that's the easy bit for me) and pass it to the javascript (that is the hardbit as I know very little about web programming and next to nothing about javascript/html).

Comment: JB Nizet, Ok so if I create in Java String [] images = new String [IMAGE_COUNT]; how do I pass the images array to the javascript?

Comment: JB Nizet, Please ignore that I see what you're suggesting. Thanks for your help! I will see if I can incorporate your suggestion into my implementation.

Comment: Hint: `Collection#toString()` (and `Map#toString()`) happen to return exactly the JS-compatible string representation. So just `var ids = ${bean.ids};` ought to be sufficient.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for the tip. I never thought about that. It works for integers, but not for Strings, though (no quotes around them). And I find it a bit... hacky. I would prefer using JSON for this (but didn't want to go this way with the OP, who has to learn simple things first, IMHO)

Comment: JSON is definitely better. But yes, learn the basics first :)

Comment: out.println("<img width='600' height='600' src=displayphoto?id=" +  rs.getString("id") + "></img> <p/>");Now instead of invoking the displayPhoto servlet within the html how can I request the servlet fetches the image and then returns the url into my ids array?